# Typescript: Type a function with optional parameter

Tags: typescript

I am looking for typing functions with optional argument

I tried this :

```js
type MyFunctionType<T = null> = (options: T) => unknown;
const func1: MyFunctionType<{ option1: number }> = (options) => options.option1;
const func2: MyFunctionType = () => 'test';
console.log(func1({option1: 12})); // Ok
console.log(func2()); // Error : Expected 1 argument
```

typescript shows an error on func2.

So i tried with "?" on options parameter:

```js
type MyFunctionType2<T = null> = (options?: T) => unknown;
const func1: MyFunctionType2<{ option1: number }> =  (options) => options.option1;
const func2: MyFunctionType2 = () => 'test';
console.log(func2()); // Ok
console.log(func1()); // No error is raised
```

But in this case, typescript does not show error for using func1 without parameter.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Thank you for reading

Comment: The parameter is **optional**. Why should there be an error when the parameter is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using conditional types:

```
type MyFunctionType<T = null> = T extends null | undefined
    ? (options?: T) => unknown
    : (options: T) => unknown;

const func1: MyFunctionType<{ option1: number }> = (options) => options.option1;
const func2: MyFunctionType = () => 'test';

func2();
func1(); // shows an error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0."
```

This defined the generic type `MyFunctionType` to be a function whose parameter is optional in case the type of the parameter is null, undefined or the union of both. You could even leave them out entirely in this case:

```
type MyFunctionType<T = null> = T extends null | undefined
    ? () => unknown
    : (options: T) => unknown;
```

---

Arguably though, I cannot really see a usecase for a type definition like this as it will always shadow the actual return type and force a single parameter while not allowing multiple ones which might help readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
type MyFunctionType<T = never> = (options: T) => unknown;
```

Comment: In a TS Playground this also shows a compiler error for func2 getting called without arguments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).